# Module Not found after attaching volume in docker

Tags: docker, express, dockerfile, docker-volume, docker-for-windows

This is my dockerfile

```yaml
FROM node:15
# sets the folder structure to /app directory
WORKDIR /app
# copy package.json to /app folder
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
# Copy all files from current directory to current directory in docker(app)
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node","index.js"]
```

I am using this command in my powershell to run the image in a container

```
docker run -v ${pwd}:/app -p 3000:3000 -d --name node-app node-app-image
```

> `${pwd}`
> returns the current directory.
> But as soon as I hit enter, somehow node_modules isn't being installed in the container and I get "express not found" error in the log.
> [![Docker log][1]][1]
> I can't verify if node_modules isn't being installed because I can't get the container up to run the `exec --it` command.

---

> I was following a freecodecamp tutorial and it seems to work in his pc and I've tried this command in command prompt too by replacing ${pwd} by %cd%.

---

This used to work fine before I added the volume flag in the command.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fifu.png

Comment: When you map your current directory to /app with `-v ${pwd}:/app`, you hide everything that's installed in `/app` in the image and replace it with what's in your current directory on the host machine.

Comment: Does deleting the `-v` option resolve the problem?  That will let Docker use the code and `node_modules` tree from the image.  You can use a host-based Node environment for day-to-day development even if you'll eventually deploy via Docker.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem was you build your image somewhere and then try to map another folder to it.

```
|_MyFolder/
  |_ all-required-files
  |_ all-required-folders
  |_ Dockerfile
```

`docker build -t node-app-image .`

`docker run -p 3000:3000 -d --name node-app node-app-image`

Simplified Dockerfile

```
FROM node:15
# sets the folder structure to /app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy all files from current directory to current directory in docker(app)
COPY . ./

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node","index.js"]
```

Comment: No, that didn't work either. I'm still getting the same error. I even tried adding absolute path instead of ${pwd} and still same error.

Comment: When you create docker image, it takes `Dockerfile` located  location and copy all into the docker image. When you try to map volumes, that directory is overriden.